Spherical harmonics, special functions and special polynomials
Does the spherical harmonics, special functions, and special polynomials have their origin in the theory of differential equations?

Yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions

Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

I can't tell about all special functions/polynomials occuring in physics.
But many (or may be even most) of them are solutions
of certain  differential equations.
For example:
The spherical harmonics $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ are solutions
of the differential equations
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial Y}{\partial\theta}\right)
+\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2Y}{\partial\phi^2}&=-l(l+1)Y \\
\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial\phi^2}&=-m^2Y
\end{align}$$
The Bessel functions $J_n(x)$ are solutions of
Bessel's differential equation
$$x^2\frac{d^2J}{dx^2}+x\frac{dJ}{dx}+(x^2-n^2)J=0$$
The Hermite polynomials $H_n(x)$are solutions of
Hermite's differential equation
$$\frac{d^2H}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dH}{dx}+2nH=0$$

It seems that the answer indeed lies in the theory of differenital equations. Thanks for giving this useful direction.
